# Calculate the derivative w.r.t. a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix and $v\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ be a vector. $$f(v):\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}  \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, f(v)=(vv^T+aI)^{-1}P$$ where $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}^+$ is a constant and $P\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Let $g(v)=\|f(v)-Q\|_F^2$ ,where $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

I want to calculate $\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial v}$.

I know $\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial f}=2(f(v)-Q)$.

But I do not know $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial v}$. Because the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. And $v$ is a vector. What's the dimension of $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial v}$ should be?

Comment: Study it componentwise. $f(v)$ is a matrix with components $f(v)_{ij}$ dependent on all $v_k$, so the derivative is a three-index quantity: $\partial f_{ij}/\partial v_k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with applying the chain rule to matrix problems is it often requires derivatives (which are higher order tensors) for some of the intermediate steps.

It is far easier to work with differentials, since the differential of a matrix/vector is just another matrix/vector, and not a higher order object.

Anyway, define a few symbols to cast the problem into something easier to manipulate.

Let 
$$ \eqalign {
X &= (vv^T+aI) = X^T \cr
f &= X^{-1}\cdot P \cr
h &= f-Q \cr
M &= f\cdot h^T\cdot X^{-1} \cr
g &= h:h
} $$

We just need one well-known rule for the differential of an inverse to get started:
$$ \eqalign {
dX^{-1} &= -X^{-1}\cdot dX\cdot X^{-1} \cr
} $$

So the differential of g is
$$ \eqalign {
dg &= 2h:dh \cr
   &= 2h:df \cr
   &= 2h:(dX^{-1}\cdot P) \cr
   &= 2h:(-X^{-1}\cdot dX\cdot X^{-1}\cdot P) \cr
   &= 2h:(-X^{-1}\cdot dX\cdot f) \cr
   &= -2X^{-T}\cdot h\cdot f^T:dX \cr
   &= -2M^T:dX \cr
   &= -2M^T:d(vv^T) \cr
   &= -2M^T:(dv\,v^T + v\,dv^T)) \cr
   &= -2(M + M^T):v\,dv \cr
   &= -2v^T\cdot(M + M^T)\cdot dv \cr
} $$

The above steps used only differentials of vectors/matrices, no higher-order tensors were needed.  Now we can identify the derivative as:
$$ \eqalign {
\frac {\partial g} {\partial v} &= -2v^T\cdot(M + M^T) \cr
} $$

The remaining task is to cast the result into a form that you like, e.g.
$$ \eqalign {
\frac {\partial g} {\partial v} &= -2v^T\cdot\bigg[f\cdot(f^T-Q^T)\cdot X^{-1} + X^{-1}\cdot(f-Q)\cdot f^T\bigg] \cr
} $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have a question about $d(vv^T)$. In your answer, $d(vv^T)=(dv\ v+v \ dv)$. Could you please tell me how did you get this equation. In the comment of Simen, 'so the derivative is a three-index quantity'. Is this a 3D?

Comment: Simen's observation was that $\partial{f}/\partial{v}$ is one of those higher order tensors, you'd need if you apply the chain rule, i.e. multiply it with $\partial{g}/\partial{f}$. $vv^T$ and its differential are merely matrices.